# ng-repeat fails with infdig error

Tags: angularjs

I understand the issue with 10 digest iterations is a topic of much discussion around here, but I could not really find a solution that works for me. Forgive my ignorance, I am still a novice.

My scope variable looks like this:

```
    $scope.output = {"0":{"Error Count : ":{"0":"0 in MS1","1":"0 in MS2","2":"0 in MS3","3":"0 in MS4"}}}
```

I am trying to iterate through using

```
    <div ng-repeat="out in output">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in out">
            {{key}}
                <div ng-repeat="valy in val">
                    {{valy}}
                </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Which throws me an infdig error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing your controller. But it's better to handle all that iteration in the controller anyway.

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/Pickra/pen/GMxvyz)

### TEMPLATE

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrlr">
        <div ng-repeat="out in output">
            <div ng-bind-html="getOutputValue(out)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller("Ctrlr", ["$scope", "$sce", function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.output = {
        "0":{
            "Error Count : ": {
                "0":"0 in MS1",
                "1":"0 in MS2",
                "2":"0 in MS3",
                "3":"0 in MS4"
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.getOutputValue = (output) => {
        // Loop over the ouptut keys and reduce all the output to a string
        const stuff = Object.keys(output).reduce((acc, key) => {
            // Get child values and put them in a string of <div>s
            const childVals = Object.values(output[key])
                .map(val => `<div>${val}</div>`)
                .join("");

            // Create string for each iteration
            const iterationString = `<div>${key} ${childVals}</div>`;

            // Update accumulator string with current iteration string
            acc = `${acc} ${iterationString}`;
            return acc;
        }, "");

        // ... use angular $sce to pass HTML string to template
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(`${stuff}`);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am having trouble running the DEMO. Can you check if this is working as expected?

Comment: The DEMO works. I just checked. Don't know why you'd be having trouble.

Comment: Thanks @Ari just realized it works on Chrome and not on IE. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: "=>" notation is not supported in IE11. Can I use this using normal functions like $scope.getOutputValue = function(output)

Comment: Yes, user4923462 you can. I just used fat arrows for brevity.

Comment: Check the [MDN fat arrow docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) browser compatibility for future reference.

Comment: Thank You @Ari. I used babeljs.io to convert your code to ES5 compatible code.